# Return a placeholder image when FirebaseImage returns null in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm displaying an image from Firebase Storage using [Firebase Image Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_image)

It'll be a toss up if a photo is actually there, and I want to return a placeholder if it is not.  I can't seem to figure out how to return the placeholder if the original FirebaseImage is null.

Using a get or other reference guarantees a read and/or download for every iteration, so I'm trying to reference using the cache feature of Image Provider first...but I can't find any documentation on how to handle this kind of a null return...it seems different, since my code below isn't working.

```
Center(
     child: new CircleAvatar(
       radius: Grid.hSafeBlock * 16.5,
       backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
       backgroundImage: FirebaseImage(
         'gs://location/images/$reference.jpg',
          shouldCache: true,) ??
       FirebaseImage('gs://location/images/$other_reference.png',
          shouldCache: true,),
```

The error in the console is this:

The following PlatformException was thrown resolving an image codec:
PlatformException(Error -13010, FIRStorageErrorDomain, Object location/reference.jpg does not exist., null)

Code works fine if image is there.  Code works fine if the placeholder value is the primary value.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/mattreid1/firebase_image/issues/11#issuecomment-646508879

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that already.  My issue was the actual coding to get me there.  I figured it out and posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using a FutureBuilder in conjunction with a getMetaData in this way, which seems to be doing the trick.  However, I'm open to better ideas and advice here.

```
      Center(
            child: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
                future: getCardImage(facility: facility, pictureID: id),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return CircleAvatar(
                      radius: avatarRadius,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      backgroundImage: FirebaseImage(
                        'gs://location/$images/$reference.jpg',
                        shouldCache: true,
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return CircleAvatar(
                        radius: avatarRadius,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/some_other_photo.png',
                          color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                          width: imageSize,
                        ));
                  }
                }),
          ),
```

This function looks for metaData, which is a different category of read with firebase as I understand it, which saves both normal reads and the data transfer using the cache functionality. (Someone correct me if I'm wrong).

```
 Future getCardImage({String facility, String pictureID}) async {
return await FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('images')
    .child('$facility')
    .child('$pictureID.jpg')
    .getMetadata();
```

}

Comment: Usually getDownloadURL() is used. If returns url, set your image else use placeholder image:

    ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) {
      image = FirebaseImage('gs://example.jpg');
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('No Image on FB Storage!');
    });